# Fix the block quote the default text to only select the text and not the > on the iOS app

Tags: bug, markdown, ios-app

When I press the"Button on I was at, it very nicely inserts default text:

> > Block quote

The inserted text from > to e is selected (COOL). It would be really cool if the > and space were not selected so we could paste in the text to be quoted without obliterating the > and space.

Note, the programming of the code button works as I hope. It inserts the space, and then select only the text "enter code here" but perhaps that is due to the insertion being white space instead of an actual character due to how markdown is defined.

This bug exists in (v1.0.0.67) of the iOS app

Comment: Ha! Yeah selecting all of it kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it? (You can also paste first, then select, then press `"` btw)

Comment: For me on iOS, when I select text and press **"**, it replaces the selected text with **"** - did you mean the nice {} icon instead of `"`?

Comment: The block quote button from the markdown keyboard menu. Next to `{}`

Comment: @mhlester Indeed - the " here was so drastically different than the icon my brain struggled to understand initially what you were suggesting. Yes, pasting the text to be formatted, selecting that text and then selecting the button works as I expect it to.

Comment: This doesn't discount the issue you're reporting. Just a workaround. You still get my +1